# Installing Ogre with CMake

Tags: apt, cmake

I am trying to install Ogre software with CMake but it says I'm missing things. I found one and installed it (freetype) but I can't find (Xaw: X11 Athena widget set) or (X Toolkit). Is there an easier way to install this?
This is all that I'm missing now.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:570 (message):
  X11 support requires Xcursor library.

After this I am unable to find it to run it. what happened to it?

Linking CXX executable ../../bin/OgreMeshUpgrader
[100%] Built target OgreMeshUpgrader

Comment: I'm also looking for Xcursor library

Comment: You should show us what are these "missing things", please copy the output, **[edit] your question** and paste it in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention what version of Ubuntu you're running nor what version of OGRE you are trying to install, however there is a `libogre-dev` package in the Precise repository, which should bring in `libogre-1.7.4`. There is also a `ogre-tools` package. You can see the various related packages for your system using `apt-cache` e.g.

```
apt-cache search --names-only ogre
```

If you really do need to install from source, then the `xorg-dev` metapackage should include `libxt-dev` and `libxaw7-dev` i.e. it should be sufficient to do

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 and Ogre 1.8.1

Answer (score 1):

X11 Athena widget set can be installed from:

```
sudo apt-get install xaw3dg
```